# How to support multiple screen sizes in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am having a problem displaying my layout in 5" or smaller screens .The smaller height of phone spills bottom views out display . I tried creating layouts using sw320dp and different dimens folder but app seems to take that smallest layout only for all type of sizes. I am unable to map the layouts properly . All I need is to make the size of views smaller in small screens.

Answer (score 1):

-You should use ConstraintLayout for Create a flexible layout
-You should use Different dpi icon for different phones like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi
-you can also take reference from Google's Documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I am already using constraint layout and it's  full features, stil there are things which cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Android Manifest xml

```
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I have added but can you explain what does this do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it will be helpful

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
```

This library will help to create flexible view items as per device screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint layout, it will effectively adjust most of your views. Along with that, as a precaution, add scrollview in layouts where you think you have too many views just so they don't go out of screen bounds on smaller screen sizes.

Constraint layout doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: I did use constraint layout in all my layouts but  I wanted to use an alternate layouts for smaller screen. But adding layout-small doesn't work. My app chooses the smaller layout for the app irrespective of the screen size . I used sw320 also still no results.